# Why is SerialGC chosen over G1GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am running Java on very similar VMs and I can't find the explanation why the SerialGC is chosen over G1GC in one case. It's the same Java version, same OS, same VM instance type on AWS, and I suspect the only difference is container settings but I do not know how to pinpoint what changes. Is there a way to get an explanation on why the VM decides to chose this settings or another?

Java version in both case:

```java
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

When running Java in one case:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlag
```

Output:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-XX:InitialHeapSize=253366976 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4053871616 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+SegmentedCodeCache -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseSerialGC
[Global flags]
(...)
   bool UseG1GC                                  = false                                    {product} {default}
     bool UseParallelGC                            = false                                    {product} {default}
     bool UseSerialGC                              = true                                     {product} {ergonomic}
```

And the other:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=8 -XX:InitialHeapSize=253480064 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4055681024 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+SegmentedCodeCache -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC
[Global flags]
(...)
   bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                    {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseParallelGC                            = false                                    {product} {default}
     bool UseSerialGC                              = false                                     {product} {default}
```

Comment: You say "very similar vms". That implies that there are differences. Did you check that -version really gives the exact same result.

Comment: Well yeah this is what I am trying to pinpoint. The java is exactly the same (adding it to the original question) - as the whole docker image. But it's a different AWS AMI and we deploy the image differently (k8s instead of docker directly).

Comment: Is it possible your VM which is using Serial collector has only one CPU?

Comment: I ran `cat /proc/cpuinfo` in both cases and can see the 8 vCPUs in both cases.

Comment: I realize you are using docker/k8s. So I think what matters is the number of cpus given to the docker container, not to the VM. Can you check that as well - number of cpus, cpu quota and/or cpu shares given to docker container.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`{ergonomic}` in `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` means that the flag was set automatically based on the number of available processors and the amount of RAM.

JDK 10 [treats machine as "server"](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/hotspot/share/runtime/os.cpp#l1606) if it has at least 2 available CPUs and 2 GB RAM. This can be overriden by 
`-XX:+AlwaysActAsServerClassMachine` or `-XX:+NeverActAsServerClassMachine` JVM flags.

"Server" configuration assumes [G1 as the default GC](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcArguments.cpp#l72), while "Client" machine uses [SerialGC](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcArguments.cpp#l72) by default.

To calculate the number of available processors JDK uses not only the CPUs visible in the OS, but also processor affinity and cgroup limits, including

- cpu.shares
- cpu.cfs_quota_us
- cpuset.cpus

Since you run Java in a container, it's likely that container imposes cgroup limits that result in a smaller number of available CPUs or amount of memory. Use `-Xlog:os+container=trace` to find the effective limits in each particular environment.

Comment: Great thanks. It turned out it was a regression in the ubuntu used on the host, things are working fine now. But it's interesting to get some insights on how this is decided!